# PostCSS: ExtractTextPlugin run twice

Tags: javascript, postcss

I am trying to create a new postcss plugin. The problem is that when I am using the `ExtractTextPlugin`, the code is run twice, so if, for example, I'm appending new rule, it will append this twice.

I was looking for a solution and people are suggested to add `allChunks: true`, but it does not work.

```
css.walkRules(function (rule) {

    rule.walkDecls(function (decl, i) {

       // this is run twice with ExtractTextPlugin

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to just remove the `fallback: "style-loader"` from `webpack.config` file.